# Delimiting some sibling nodes without additional element

Tags: angularjs, templates, handlebars.js

What is the equivalent angularjs template for the following handlebar template? Is there any way to achieve same result without wrapping the if block with another tag?
(foo is false)

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    {{if foo}}
    <li>b</li>
       … 
    <li>c</li>
    {{/if}}
    <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

The rendered template should be exactly:

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works, similar to `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`. However, I did not find it on the docs.

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li ng-if-start='foo'>b</li>
       … 
    <li ng-if-end>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) with one time binding(if you are in version 1.3.x else resort to some other libraries like bindonce to avoid any unnecessary watches) might be more appropriate for you.  But ideally it is clearly unclear because you can solve this with many ways in angular. It does not even has to get to the view, you could just filter it out from the controller itself while setting up the view model which is used to repeat (`ng-repeat`) the `li`s. `ng-show` can also be used if you are trying to show and hide them. Difference between ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide is that ng-if removes the element completely from dom (and it cannot be animated with nganimate). ng-show just sets the css property display:none if condition set is false.

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li ng-if="::foo">b</li><!-- Using :: for one time binding V1.3.x so no more watchers -->
    <li ng-if="::foo">c</li>
    <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

**Update** based on the comment that OP is looking for "a block statement to show/hide a bunch of elements together without adding a container tag".

Angular is not just a templating library like handlebars. So first thing before providing any specific answer is to recommend to [learn how angular works](http://learn-angular.org/). It is much more than a templating engine, it binds data to DOM that is already rendered and view is more of a reflection of the view model/model built from the controller. So in your case, as i explained earlier you just have to filter out the data based on a specific condition. Take a look at [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), event DOM [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) that can be used with ng-repeat. So in short looking for a `a block statement to show/hide a bunch of elements together without adding a container tag` in angular (just what you would in handlebars) is thinking in wrong direction in my opinion. A possible solution for you can as well just be to identify when `foo` becomes true do not event provide those items (to be filtered out) to be rendered to view (or works case use filters in the view). And adding a block statement can just result in an invalid html in your case and browser will just strip it off before even angular has a chance to process it (unlike handlerbars where you transform your template to html before even rendering).

Here is one possible, better way (Using view filters are bad if filtering is one time, if it is just one time do the filtering in the controller) to do this in my opinion.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
      name: 'a',
      hideWhenFoo: false
    }, {
      name: 'b',
      hideWhenFoo: false
    }, {
      name: 'c',
      hideWhenFoo: true
    }, {
      name: 'd',
      hideWhenFoo: true
    }, {
      name: 'e',
      hideWhenFoo: true
    }, {
      name: 'f',
      hideWhenFoo: false
    }, {
      name: 'g',
      hideWhenFoo: false
    }];
    $scope.foo = true; // due to some condition
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{hideWhenFoo:!foo}">{{item.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a lot of `li`s. I am looking for a block statement to show/hide a bunch of elements together without adding a container tag.